# Pull Down Amortizations in a Pyramid Style

Tags: excel, vba, jobs, amortization

I work at a company and have been tasked with creating a macro to pull down amortizations for each period in a pyramid style similar to the style below. I can not use actual numbers for privacy reasons. Is there any macros that can be used that would simplify this process so that I do not have to type in all the information for the next set so on and so forth?

[image]

This is the macro I have designed so far, (its not based on the example but on the actual workpaper used). I am trying to see if there is a way for the macro to select the next data field in the corresponding column.

[image]

This is my first time asking help online for this sort of problem so if there are any issues please let me know.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead, include the code in your question as text that people can copy/paste if they want to.

Comment: Tips to get started: Instead of `Range("O31").Select` and `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ...` you can just write `Range("O31").FormulaR1C1 = ...`. This will also be faster and make the screen less jittery. Whenever you're making multiple changes to the sheet, I also suggest turning off calculation temporarily `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and then returning it to automatic at the end of the macro `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

Comment: To make automation easier, you can use loops to simplify multiple repeated lines of code into a single statement. For example you could write `For r = 21 To 32` and then your range could be `Range("O" & r)`. This would let you "loop" from O21 to O32. You could define other variables which help you calculate the R1C1 formula based on the current value of `r`.